# $E(T(X))$ where $A:={n(\bar X-\mu)^2\over \sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{(1)}$ ; $B:={\sum\limits_i(X_i-\bar X)^2\over \sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)}$

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator

> $X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n$ is a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I have to find out

> an unbiased estimator of ${\mu\over \sigma}$

My work:

Initially I take $T(X)={\bar X\over \sqrt{{1\over n}\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2}}$ I need to find $E(T(X))$.

I know

> $A:={\sqrt n(\bar X-\mu)\over \sigma}\sim N(0,1)$ ; $B:={\sum\limits_i(X_i-\bar X)^2\over \sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)}$

But how to find out $E(T(X))$ if I know $E(A)$ and $E(B)$ seperately?

My thoughts:

> The fact that $\bar X$  is independent of $\sum\limits_i(X_i-\bar X)^2$might be of help.
>
> Some modification of ${A\over B}$ might lead to the $t$ distribution.

Please help me proceed.

Comment: You know an unbiased estimator of $\mu$. Can you find an unbiased estimator of $1/\sigma$?

Comment: @whuber oh! Is it using gamma function?

Comment: Relevant answer on Math.SE:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066941/321264.